# can I recover encrypted image files from an old Android phone where I know the pin used but the device key is unknown?

Tags: encryption

I think I know the OS version that was used to encrypt the images but I don't know if that is relevant. I assume if I know the encryption algorithm/software used (ie. CryptFS) and can brute force the device key I could recover the images. The phone was secured only with a numeric PIN. I also would need to know what kind of software I could use to do this process and if it would be possible. Thanks.

Comment: The OS version should give a clue about what algorithm was used to unlock / derive the device key. The key itself (probably) was stored in an encrypted form using a key derived from the PIN. If you have this encrypted master key, the PIN and the specification for decrypting the master key, you can decrypt arbitrary data that was encrypted under this key. If you're asking for tools that do all (or parts) of the above for you, this is the wrong site. If you want to know how the master key is derived, given a specific OS version (which we needed then), this would be on-topic.

Comment: yes, knowing how the master key is derived from the PIN would be ideal. The Samsung Stratosphere had to have been running Gingerbread - Android OS 2.3.

Comment: [Closest information I could find is about 5.0 :(](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/)